# Database PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to make an assignment for school but I get two errors:

> Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting on of the following:
>   constant exception `<an identifier>` `<a double-quoted
>   delimited-identifier>` table LONG_ double ref char time timestamp
>   interval date binary national character nchar

and

> Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
>   following: end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
>   member constructor map

Here is the link to my code: http://pastebin.com/h4JN9YQY

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generate_bonus
AS

cursor student_info is
    select distinct students.id,
  events.begindatetime,
    events.enddatetime,
    count(items.number_of_coupons) as coupons_collected,
    events.type from students
    join applies on applies.students_id = students.id
    join schedules on schedules.id = applies.schedules_id
    join events on events.id = schedules.events_id
    join orders on orders.students_id = students.id
    join orderitems on orderitems.orders_id = orders.id
    join items on items.id = orderitems.items_id
    join bars on bars.id = orders.bars_id
    where applies.status = 'PLANNED'
    and orderitems."NUMBER" is not null
    and bars.name is not null
    group by students.id, events.begindatetime, events.enddatetime, events.type
    order by students.id;

BEGIN

    DECLARE
    s_id integer(256);
    s_beginDate date;
    s_endDate date;
    s_noCoupons number(256);
    s_eventType varchar2(256);
    s_workedHours number(24) := 8;
    calculated_bonus number(256);
    count_rows integer(256);

    OPEN student_info;

        LOOP

        FETCH student_info into s_id, s_beginDate, s_endDate, s_noCoupons, s_eventType;

            Select count(*) into count_rows from student_bonus where students_id = s_id and rownum <= 1;

      EXIT WHEN count_rows = 1;

            IF (s_eventType = 'ROUGH') THEN
                calculated_bonus := s_workedHours * (s_workedHours / 100 * 7) * s_noCoupons;

                INSERT INTO student_bonus(students_id, bonus, events_id) VALUES (s_id, calculated_bonus, s_eventType);

                calculated_bonus := 0;

            ELSIF (s_eventType = 'NORMAL') THEN
                calculated_bonus := s_workedHours * (s_workedHours / 100 * 4) * s_noCoupons;

                INSERT INTO student_bonus(students_id, bonus, events_id) VALUES (s_id, calculated_bonus, s_eventType);

                calculated_bonus := 0;

            ELSE
                calculated_bonus := s_workedHours * (s_workedHours / 100 * 2) * s_noCoupons;

                INSERT INTO student_bonus(students_id, bonus, events_id) VALUES (s_id, calculated_bonus, s_eventType);

                calculated_bonus := 0;
            END IF;

        END LOOP;

    CLOSE student_info;

END generate_bonus;
```

Comment: Paste your code directly here.

Comment: Please read up about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is unlikely that what you show is anything close to an MCVE.

Comment: If your count_rows starts with 0, you'll loop forever i guess, perhaps changing it to "exit when count_rows<=1" would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion much easier for juniors to use is cursor loop, in this project You will avoid this kind of errors. Syntax like:

```
FOR row_variable IN cursor LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(row_variable.id);
END LOOP;
```

row_variable holds valeus from each cursor row, and you can easily acces it with '.' (dot) operator like row_variable.id
Using cursor loop lets You avoid problems with fetching data, taking care about open/close cursor and worry about output outside cursor space.
The loop will make loops exactly how many items cursor is pointing, like for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

put this line:

`EXIT WHEN student_info%NOTFOUND`;

after this line:

```
FETCH student_info into s_id, s_beginDate, s_endDate, s_noCoupons, s_eventType;
```

You had reached the end of your cursor but there is no code which tells it to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor should follow steps in following manner..

```
Open Cursor
LOOP
 FETCH cursor
 EXIT Cursor condtion

{--
Your rest of the code here
--}

end loop;
```